# Asp.net mvc httpthandler redirection to inner server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, httphandler

I want to create an http handler that sends request to **url** that comes with querystring parameter. Because the **url** parameter is backend server. Users can not access it so I want to send request with a proxy script.

```
http://frontendserver?url=http://backendserver?x=1&y=2

  public class GeolocateRequestHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            TransferUserIfAuthenticated(new HttpContextWrapper(context));
        }

        private static void TransferUserIfAuthenticated(HttpContextBase context)
        {
            if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var url = context.Request.QueryString["url"];
                ??? redirect to url (locale lan server)
            }
        }
    }
```

Should I do via a .Net WenClient object or is there a short way else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WebClient` is used to create a new Request and get Response.

You can make redirection in current context using it's Response object.

```
context.Response.Redirect(url)
```

**EDIT**

I can't give you exact working code, by I'll explain in theory.

Perform a request with `HttpWebRequest`. Get response and rewrite data into `context.Response`.

You have to rewrite content, headers(like content-type), cookies if needed.

```
var http = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com");
var response = (HttpWebResponse)http.GetResponse();
```

Comment: sorry I changed question so you can check your answer.